# How to match exact digits count by using regex in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to find 3 digits after **all dots** *(.)*. If I give input **"1.22.222"**, it should return ***false***. If I give **"1.222.222"** then it should return ***true***. I have tried the below regex but it didn't work.

```
var reg1 = new RegExp("\\.\\d{3}");
var reg2 = new RegExp("\\.\\d{3,3}");
reg1.test("1.22.222") // returns true, but i need to return false.
```

How to resolve this.

Comment: What is "didn't work"? What's the current behavior?

Comment: According to what you're saying, the code is doing exactly that. In `1.22.222` there are 3 digits `222` after the dot `.`. What do you want **exactly**?

Comment: so, what about [this](https://regex101.com/r/rpbI2n/1)

Comment: I need to find 3 digits after the dot (.)

Comment: Yes, there are 3 digits `222` after the dot `.`. So the regex matching is the expected behavior.

Comment: @user202729 yes but after the first dot, there are 2 digits only. Then it should return false. Clear?

Comment: So specify your problem in your question clearly. **For all** dots, there are 3 digits after it.

Comment: @MJNBelief No, it is just example. it may be like "1.222.222.22.22.222".

Comment: ... regex can't `text`, but it can probably `test`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this `^\d(\.\d{3})+$`

[Online demo](https://regex101.com/r/rpbI2n/7)

Comment: [Doesn't work](https://tio.run/##HYzBCsIwEETv/Yo9CE3QpgTPHv2Beu2hoVliJCYlu7QF8dtjKgwMD97My6yG5uwX7mKyWIjhBg/OPjqVzTYVLUY12s/1K8@nMikKfkahL52W0PeQ8Z1WBH4iBDS2rsBEC5yNDwdE3Gpjk9HhXp8rw4Duvi@CWDZzipQCqpCc@CuKkVi0WukjupWy/AA). You need a `^`.

Comment: `regExp = new RegExp("^(\\.\\d{3})+$");
regExp.test("1.222.222.333") // false`
Does not work as expected.

Comment: @Raja It returns true, you're doing something wrong. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYxBCsMgFET3OcVfFKK0MRjXXfYC7TaLSPxYi9WgnyRQenZrsxiGB2/mpVed5@QW6kI0WDLBFR6UXLAi6W0qko1iNB/15edTmUT2bkYmL53k0PeQ8B1XBHoieNSmrkAHA5S0838IuNXGJqHFvT5Xhjva276wTLyZY8jRo/DRskMRhJlYK8UwDEeUUi3n5Qc)

Comment: @MJNBelief Fails in this case. `regExp.test("2.222.222.333")`

Comment: for any digit in first line just use `\d` ,answer updated

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could use [`^[^\.]+(?:\.\d{3})+$`](https://regex101.com/r/4EmkLE/1)

**This will match**

```
^         # From the beginning of the string
[^\.]+    # match NOT a dot one or more times
(?:       # A non capturing group
  \.\d{3} # Match a dot and 3 digits
)         # Close non capturing group and repeat one or more times
$         # The end of the string
```

Answer (score 0):

var reg = new RegExp("^\d(\.\d{3})")

var out = reg.test("1.222.222")
console.log(out) // true

var out = reg.test("1.22.222")
console.log(out) // false

var out = reg.test("1.222.22")
console.log(out) // false

Answer (score -2):

It need to begin with something before dot, and end with 3 digits before dot

```
var reg = new RegExp("^\\d(\\.\\d{3})+$");
var out = reg.test("1.222.222")
console.log(out) // true
var out = reg.test("1.22.222")
console.log(out) // false
var out = reg.test("1.222.22")
console.log(out) // false
```